# Custom button doesn't work in Salesforce 1 and Lightning Experience

Tags: salesforce1-app, button, custom

Actually, I'm using the following link behind a custom button(Type:Detail Page Button) on the Account:

```
http://mapy.group.com/atreport?AccountID={!CASESAFEID(Account.Id)}&UserID={!$User.Id}&SessionID={!$Api.Session_ID}
```

I works fine in Classic but in Salesforce 1 and in Lightning Experience, I face the issue:

> Error Data Request, Erreur 400:401

Any idea to turn this button to work Salesforce1 and Lightning Experience ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Custom buttons are **not** supported in Lightning Experience, as stated below:

> Custom buttons that use a JavaScript content source aren’t supported in Lightning Experience. Check out Lightning Alternatives to JavaScript Buttons in Trailhead for a great list of Lightning-friendly solutions for your JavaScript button use cases.

Kindly check out alternatives [here](https://trailhead.salesforce.com/en/modules/lex_javascript_button_migration) to Custom Buttons in Lightning experience and SF1.

Comment: Glad it helped. Kindly go through [this](http://salesforce.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers) particular help topic to learn about , what-to-do when someone answers your question.